# How do I import contacts from MIT App Inventor into a database (tinydb or firebase)?

Tags: database, sqlite, firebase, app-inventor, tinydb

I currently have the capability to get contacts to show up one by one when I click the button text for button 2. How can I get contact information to automatically upload to a database (tinydb or firebase) with a button click? the ultimate goal is to eventually get this data into sqllite. Please see the screen shots below for reference.[image]

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try the [Read Contact extension](https://community.thunkable.com/t/read-contact-extension-paid-extension/7380?u=taifun) by Andres Daniel